# Changing metadata after uploading binary

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I have a simple question.

Can I change metadata (like a "keywords" field or "support URL") in the "Metadata and Uploads" section in itunesconnect.apple.com, AFTER I upload the binary, but BEFORE the app will be submitted?

Thanks.